# Compile different languages on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

I wish to code and compile different languages(e.g. C++, Java) on my [Eclipse IDE](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), but I have no idea how to do that. Do I require additional plugins for the IDE or simply download multiple language-specified IDEs?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either.

In an existing Eclipse install you can use 'Install New Software' to add the plug-ins for other languages.

Or you can download and install separate Eclipse installs for each language.